# Occlusion culling works for dynamic objects as well

Tags: unity-game-engine, occlusion, occlusion-culling

For some reason my occlusion culling **works also for dynamic objects**.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Why occlusion culling disable **non static** objects?

btw its works even when occlusion culling disabled in camera, why?

[image]

Comment: Is it an issue? I would occlusion culling expect to do this .. does it matter if your object is not within camera visible space anyway?

Comment: It supposed to work like so only for static objects, but dont

Answer (score 0):

When **Dynamic Occlusion** is enabled, Unity’s occlusion culling
system culls this Renderer when it is blocked from a Camera’s view by a Static Occluder. Otherwise, the system does not cull this Renderer when it is blocked from a Camera’s view by a Static Occluder.

Disable Dynamic Occlusion checkbox from the object's Mesh Renderer component.

Comment: i just did it, but it still dissappear even with disabled dynamic occlusion, idk why

Comment: The object is in the camera's range ? Because in the manual also says that "Cameras perform frustum culling". So if you are not looking to the object or the object is too far from the "far" distance of the camera, it will be culled by the automatic frustum culling.

Comment: no, even when camera close to object it got disabled anyway. even when i can see visibility lines